# Improving Blazor rebuild speeds

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, msbuild-4.0

When making changes to my Blazor server project, which is quite massive now, the rebuild takes approximately 30 seconds.  In some cases, this is serving as an impediment to productivity. Hot reload is, so far as I can tell, almost completely useless in my case.

If I break this project into smaller ones, would this then reduce the rebuild times, assuming I only change one of the sub projects?

If this is advisable, how would I go about coordinating those sub-projects into a single functioning Blazor project, with shared services and so on?

Comment: You'll have to get the architecture right or it'll only get worse. Take a look at Clean Architecture, and use interfaces to decouple modules.  But this is too broad for an answer here.

Comment: I've now purchased and assembled parts for an i9-based system.  It seems the build time is down to about 10 seconds now.  But I agree-- it's just a matter of time.

Comment: Yes, unless there's a glitch, breaking up your Blazor project into smaller ones should definitely produce the desired outcome if you only make changes to one of them.  This is a general truism not just in Blazor, and not just in C#.

Comment: I haven't seen how to merge multiple Blazor projects.  Is it just like any other C# project?

Comment: A a powerful and high clock rate processor together with a gen 4 NVME  system drive should reduce the compilation times significantly.

Comment: Yeah, I built a new system with an i9, and the build times are down a lot.  But still, 10-15 seconds to rebuild * 100 rebuilds in a busy day, and that's 20-30 minutes of down time that I want back.  I'm currently trying to move finished components to a Razor class library, so that I rebuild just the core with new components.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this, by the way, is quite simple.  You can build a Razor class library project.

My current process is to build and edit new components in the main project, then move them to the library when I won't want to work on them for a while.

Comment: A more accurate answer is to distribute the components across multiple projects. I work in a solution that contains a project with about 5k Blazor components. The project takes 7 minutes to compile. Now we are looking how to split this project into small ones. In my opinion, 5K components is not big for a real world ERP system (common components like form components, ... are in other projects)